# Getting an error using listen function from the speech recognition library

Tags: python, speech-recognition

```
def TakeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer
    mic = sr.Microphone()
    with mic as source:
        print("I am listening ....")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing....")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-US')
        print(query)

    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
        print("Sorry, I didn't recognized it. Please repeat...")
TakeCommand()
```

I am getting an error on the line ''audio = r.listen(sourse)' It is says, let me quote 'listen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source' ''

And in case the link to the image:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEYOt.png

Comment: you need `r = sr.Recognizer()`, not `r = sr.Recognizer`. Every available example I've seen has `r = Recognizer()`, with the parentheses. For instance, on the [official PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/1.3.0/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - TypeError: listen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770064/python-typeerror-listen-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `r = sr.Recognizer` to `r = sr.Recognizer()`.